# Plotting a time delay in mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I'm having some difficulty plotting a phase space of a function `f` that exhibits time delay.

i.e.

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t - τ]], x[0] == 1 }, {x}, {t, 100}];
ParametricPlot[{x[t] /. s, x[t-τ] /. s}, PlotRange -> All]
```

i.e. how do I plot `x(t-τ)` vs `x(t)` ?

Comment: You don't show any information on v[t].

Comment: apologies, those should all be x[t]. fixed!

Comment: And also no information on f[x[t]].

Comment: It's just a generic function.

Comment: Okay, no generic solution.

Comment: is there any reason why? If I were using matlab for instance, I'd just have to plot x(1:end-tau) vs x(1+tau:end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References:

- [Tutorial: How To Solve Delay Differential Equations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/SolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html)
- [Syntax for ParametricPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

The following examples where (1) `s` is defined as a function of a numeric argument $\tau$, and (2) `ParametricPlot` is supplied with the parameter argument (`{t,0,10}`) that it needs, work as you intended:

```
 ClearAll[s];
 f = Cos;
 s[τ_?NumericQ] :=   NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t - τ]], x[0] == t}, {x},
  {t, 100}];
 Quiet@ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{ x[t - #] /. First@s[#], x[t] /. First@s[#]} & /@ 
    {1, 2, 3, 4}],  {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Another example with a non-constant initial function:

```
  ClearAll[s2]; 
  s2[τ_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t - τ]], 
        x[t /; t <= τ] == t}, {x}, {t, 100}]; 
  Quiet@ParametricPlot[ Evaluate[{x[t - #] /. First@s2[#], x[t] /. 
     First@s2[#]} & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4}], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and, for the constant initial function in your example:

```
 ClearAll[s3];
 s3[τ_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t - τ]], x[0] == 0.},
   {x}, {t, 100}]; 
 Quiet@ ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t - #] /. First@s3[#], x[t] /. 
    First@s3[#]} & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4}], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]